# Except no App Theme , All other Themes are showing rendering problems

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]

While using Android Studio 2.1.2 I tried using themes from app theme bar.But except no App theme ,All others are showing rendering problems?
So,What is to be done exactly to sort it out?
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

try to decrease the API level ,
https://i.stack.imgur.com/goj0J.png

Answer (score 0):

in your image click this

[image]

and set it 23 or lower.

Comment: post your `build.gradle` file

Comment: I have posted it in answer section.

Comment: @PriyankitAcharya try `clean` the project.

Comment: @PriyankitAcharya No I mean that go to `Android Studio` Menu click `Build` Menu and `Select Clean Project`.

Comment: OK.I did it.But still the rendering problems are showing

Comment: @PriyankitAcharya Make sure you have update your `support library`.

Answer (score 0):

build.gradle files

[build.gradle(Project:MyApplication2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sek5D.jpg)

[build.gradle(Module:app)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSM7J.jpg)